# C# create drawing object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The following code is an example from MSDN:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, 
   System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pe) 
{
   // Declares the Graphics object and sets it to the Graphics object
   // supplied in the PaintEventArgs.
   Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
   // Insert code to paint the form here.
}
```

I have some questions:

- Can we change the name of `Form1_Paint` method? I mean does it have to has "Paint" suffix? When does .net call this method? How does the framework know which method to call so it can draw images?
- I don't understand how come we just define that `Form1_Paint` method can receive 2 arguments and then magically the framework just calls the method with a reference to `object` and a reference to an `PaintEventArgs` object(pe).

I am sorry for the dumb questions but I come from mainly functional programming and I am confused with using frameworks because it seems like they are calling on their own methods. Can someone please explain it like to a 6 year old?

Comment: You need to look into events, event handlers,and delegates. The method is rename-able. You attach the method as an event handler some kind of event, and when the event is raised the method is triggered, with sender being the the events trigger (I think) and pe the data associated with the event.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091781/c-sharp-event-handler-explanation-please) and the article in the second answer by Jon Skeet have good info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment, `Form1_Paint` is an event handler for the `Paint` event.

The arguments aren't magic, they are required for this Event - i.e. if you want to bind to this event, your handler method implementation MUST match the event arguments required of it. A `PaintEventHandler` is defined as :

```
public delegate void PaintEventHandler(object sender, PaintEventArgs e);
```

By default, when you add a handler in the designer (e.g. by double clicking on a UI control or on the `Events` icon under the "lightning flash" tab), an event handler is automatically created with the default name:

```
{name of the control}_{name of event}
```

In your case, your form had the name `Form1` when the handler method was created.

You can rename the handler method, but if you so so, you'll also need to change the corresponding event binding in the `Form1.designer.cs` (i.e. change `this.Form1_Paint` in the below):

```
this.Name = "Form1";
this.Text = "Form1";
this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
```

(`+=` indicates a subscription to the event - once subscribed, when the event is raised, all subscribing methods will be invoked)

**Edit**

Since you come from a FP background, you may be interested that there is no need for an explicitly named event handler, you can also subscribe a suitably typed lambda:

```
this.Paint += (sender, pe) => 
{
   // Declares the Graphics object and sets it to the Graphics object
   // supplied in the PaintEventArgs.
   Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
   // Insert code to paint the form here.
};
```

Where `sender` and `pe` have exactly the same types as before. The designer won't do this by default, so what you can do is programmatically add the above subscription to your `Form1` constructor

Comment: So in other words, in *designer.cs files is the description of the controls e.g. their properties, attached event handlers to specific methods etc.?

Comment: Yes, the `designer.cs` file keeps track of all the controls, and their settings, which you've added at design time. You normally will not need to open this class - it should be automatically synched with your visual form design. (You can also change or override controls at run time as well, but this code should go into your `Form.cs`)

Answer (score 2):

Winforms is an event based technology, meaning events happen and its the programmer's job to decide what to do (if anything) when that event happens. In order to achieve this event based programming model that C# uses, a little magic happens.

Whenever you create a new form in your Winforms project, an associated `.designer.cs` file is created as well as your `.cs` file. The `.designer.cs` is an auto-generated file. It is used by Visual Studio to generate the designer view that you see when designing your form.

When you add a control to your form, that control is create programmically in the `.designer.cs` file and given some default values (such as size, a name and an id). That file is then parsed by the Visual Studio designer and the designer renders a designer view based on that `.designer.cs` file. You can open the `.designer.cs` file and see all the controls on your form being programmically created.

Now physical properties of a control are not the only thing being programmically created in the `.designer.cs` file. Events are also created. When you create a new event, such as the `Paint` event, what visual studio does it goes into the `.designer.cs` file and attaches an event handler to the event of that control. It then creates a method stub in your `.cs` file and it attaches that method stub to your event in the `.designer.cs` file. You are free to change the name to anything you want, as long as you don't change the parameters of the method. The name of your method in your `.CS` file must match the name in your `.designer.cs` file, so you need to change the name in both places.